# Using javascript events in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How can I attach an event to a button on the popup of a chrome extension? I read [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution) https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution and still can't make it work; the script just executes the "awesome" functions once and then my button does nothing.

PD: I'm a beginner at both Javascript and Chrome extensions, so I'm not sure where exactly am I doing something wrong. I'll add both tags, if that's ok.

Edit: I add the code for my extension, although is almost the same as in the example in the developer.chrome link.

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <script src="creatediv.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <button id="aaaa">something</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

creatediv.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('aaaa').addEventListener('click', loadDiv());
});

function loadDiv(){
    var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
    document.documentElement.appendChild(myDiv);
    myDiv.id = "mydiv";
    myDiv.innerHTML = "asdf";
    alert(123);
    return false;
};
```

When I click on the extension icon the loadDiv function gets executed: i get a window alert with 123 on it and then a div with "asdf" is appeneded to popup.html. The button "something" does nothing.

Comment: So you want a button click to call a function in the background script?

Comment: You need to show us your code if you want us to figure out what's wrong. Include your html and javascript for your popup please.

Comment: Edited with my actual code. On a second thought I don't think there's any problem with it being a chrome extension; it also doesn't work when I open popup.html as a regular website, though it worked when I used onclick().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
document.getElementById('aaaa').addEventListener('click', loadDiv);
```

This executes `loadDiv` when the event triggers while your code executes `loadDiv` when you add the listener.

Comment: Yeah, that was it! Thank you very much, this was killing me.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't catch that. +1